# Drawing over desktop in C#

Tags: c#, gdi

I've seen a few similar questions, but nothing doing exactly what I need.

I'm looking to create something similar to the old Sheep.exe program which had a little sheep on top of all of the windows that could walk around.

I found two possible solutions:

The first is to draw to the desktop's HDC. The problem is that it's not my DC and I can't control when stuff is refreshed.

The other solution would be using transparent windows. I want to have a bunch of independent images (that interact). I'm not sure whether I should use a transparent window that fills the entire screenspace and draw multiple images to that or if I should create a individual window for each image (which gets extremely inefficient when there's a lot of images.

What would be the most optimal way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF: Main window of application always on top, always maximized, background transparent, then start overlaying/animating to your hearts content.

Comment: Use of Expression Blend makes the task very easy

Comment: Do not set background to null unless there is a specific reason. In general, set it to Black or White, and set the Alpha channel to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WPF as a solution. In order to do so, you need to make sure you set the Background to {x:null} along with the AllowsTransparency="True"

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFMe.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1024" Width="768" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="{x:Null}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```